# how to use facebook api for login in my android apps?

Tags: java, php, android, json, api

i have my android apps which has its own login information for example for the first time the user must make a sign up profile which will include name ,email ,gender,and profession .now i want to use Facebook(or some one else) login info so that one may login to my app and i have the basic data like name,profession and gender .how can i do that?
I need the following information from Facebook .can i do it?  and if yes then how? please answer

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvbanner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Create an account"
            android:textColor="#FF30B430"
            android:textSize="30sp"

            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="normal" />
        <TableRow
            android:layout_below="@+id/meLbl"
            android:id="@+id/hr1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#FF30B430"></TableRow>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:id="@+id/SignUPLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etfirstname"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#FFF"

                android:hint="First Name"

                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"

                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:id="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etfirstname"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Please Type User Name"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:hint="Please Type Password"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/etConfirmPassword"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:hint="Type Password Again"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etConfirmPassword"
                android:text="Select Your Profession:"
                android:id="@+id/tvProfession"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:popupBackground="#FFF"
                android:textAlignment="center"


                android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfession"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="#FF30B430"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                android:text="Gender :"
                android:id="@+id/tvgender"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            </TextView>


            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvgender"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"

                >

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:id="@+id/Male"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"

                    android:buttonTint="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Female"
                    android:text="Female"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"

                    android:buttonTint="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etLastName"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="insert"

                />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what you have tried? For facebook login check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get user data from Facebook using their official Facebook's Android SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started on their site you can get info about integration of sdk in android app.